# Planning for database scaling and schema changes

Tags: mysql, database, neo4j, redis, arangodb

I'm doing research before I create my social network database and I've found a lot of questions/resources pertaining to graph and key-value databases for social networks. I understand there are a TON of different options and ways to implement the DB. I also understand that what the big companies do is complex and way above what I currently need (1b+ users). I also know each of the big companies have revamped their databases to account for the insane scaling they go through.

Because I don't know how the network will grow, and I don't believe I can accurately create a model that will scale to 1m users (due to unknowns such as how people will use it, how often people post, comment, etc). But I can at least try to create a database that will be easiest to scale when (if) the need arises.

Do most companies create a database to handle up to 1k users, then once they grow, they revamp it for 10k users, then 100k, etc? If they do, at each of these arbitrary numbers (because of the unknowns listed above), do companies typically change a few tables/nodes/etc, or do they completely recreate the database to take advantage of new technologies (such as moving from SQL to graph)?

I want to pick the best solution, but I'm finding the decision between graph, key-value, SQL, among others very difficult--especially with no data to know what relationships/data is most important. I believe I can create a solid system using a graph that can support up to 10k users, but I'm worried having to potentially completely reacreate the database as the system grows. Is this a worry now to avoid issues, or implement now and adapt later type problem?

Going further, if I do need to plan on complete DB restructures, does it typically make sense to use a Multi-Model NoSQL DBMS (such as OrientDB or ArangoDB)?

Comment: IMHO it's a mix; most companies try to project a reasonable amount of growth and build towards that.  A few project insane success and architect towards that, but not many.  A few don't project at all, they just slap it together and deal with the consequences later.  Important to understand though, that of the ones that build towards reasonable growth projections, probably half of them end up being wrong. No one can predict the future, so projections are often wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally think you are asking premature questions.

Seriously, even with a bad model, a database can handle 10k users.

You think about scaling, but the hardest **problem is not scaling**, it is **to come to the point where you need to scale**.

I'm sure everybody wants 1bn users, but then you are already dreaming about having a social network with 200 times more users than Github itself ? (Github has ~ 5 million users).

Also, even by thinking it ahead, you will refactor and refactor again definitely during years, and you will have more than one persistence layer, be sure of it.

Code and code good, stay lean, remain able to change quickly, deploy, show to users, refactor, test, deploy and show to users in the same day. These are the things you need to do now, not asking questions about a problem you don't have yet, you definitely have a lot of other problems to solve now ;-)

**UPDATE**

Based on your comment, you might need to think that there are questions we just can not simply answer, because we don't need your exact requirements.

I have a simple app, which uses 4 persistence layers, and this app is not yet online. I'll give you my "why" about using it and which use case :

1. Neo4j : it is the core of the application data, I use it because I love it, I know it very much (it is my job) and, as the concept of the app is quite new and can evolve rapidly, having a schemaless db is reducing a lot of the refactoring stuff. Also I have now a lot of use cases coming by building the app, which make Neo4j a good choice when you need to add features without breaking what has already been done.
2. MySQL

I use it for User accounts and profiles. Why ? Because the framework I use already has a lot of bundles integrating this kind of stuff in a couple of lines of code, the bundles are well maintained and if I would use (currently) neo4j for it, I will have to reinvent the wheel. Also all the modules I use evolve in stability and compatibility with the framework.

Of course the mysql data is coupled (minimally) with the neo4j one. But I know that this kind of data will not evolve that much, so Mysql is a good choice and in case I have to refactor some points, this will not be a huge pain.

3. Redis

I use Redis for storing analytics data, Redis is quite flexible and I can easily create new keys and add data on top of it.

4. RabbitMQ :

I use a lot of message queues, why ? For testing refactoring. I can easily process messages with multiple consumers for testing "refactoring", testing mutliple database layers while the app is running for testing changes, testing new features, testing refactoring, ...

You will refactor ! Just try to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: The second half of your answer is I was looking for. I guess I was too vague in how I asked. Addressing the first part, I know that looking to having a large user base requires a TON of other things to take into account (mainly acquisition and growth), but that's not the technical part I needed advice on. The problem was more geared towards how detrimental is it to use a database that won't be used when (if?) I can ramp up to 1m users. And for that, I seem to be getting a lot of "refactor, refactor, refactor".

Comment: Have you run into issues coupling Neo4j with MySQL? Or so long as you keep days from being stored in both, you're fine?

Comment: No I didn't. Well there might be issues, for eg if one of the both dbs is down. It is up to your strategy or requirements to block the process or accept the process to be synced later (via a mq for eg).